# Serilog does not generate logs to console or file when application is published (.net 6)

Tags: serilog

I have a worker app on .net 6. Serilog works fine (console and file logging) when running application with `dotnet run`. However, when running from executable app it doesn't log anything (does not even create log file)

I'm compiling the app with:

```
dotnet publish -r linux-x64 -c Release -o app/publish --self-contained true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:PublishReadyToRun=false -p:PublishTrimmed=false
```

The serilog.json file is:

```
{
    "Serilog": {
      "Using": [],
      "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
          "Microsoft": "Information",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
          "System": "Information",
          "MyApp.LoadData": "Information"
        }
      },
      
      "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:o}][{Level:u4}][{ThreadId}][{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        },
        {
          "Name": "File",
          "Args": {
            "buffered": true,
            "flushToDiskInterval": 15,
            "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:o}][{Level:u4}][{ThreadId}][{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
            "path": "customerscredit//logs//LoadCredit.log",
            "retainedFileCountLimit": 31,
            "rollingInverval": "Day",
            "textFormatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
          }
        }
      ],

      "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId", "WithExceptionDetails"] ,
      
      "Properties": {
        "ApplicationName": "MyApp.LoadData",
        "Product": "MyApp",
        "Env": ""
      }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in the configuration? Is there a specific way of compiling the app for Serilog to work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I tested the same application in dotnet core 5 with the same results. Furthermore, changed it to dotnet core 3.1 and it works. So it has something to do with the dotnet core version.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. From the Serilog.Settings.Configuration documentation:

> NET 5.0 Single File Applications Currently, auto-discovery of
> configuration assemblies is not supported in bundled mode. DO use
> Using section for workaround.

So, all I needed to too was set the Using as follows:

```
"Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Enrichers.Thread"]
```